# Find UMVUE of $P(X_1+X_2+X_3 =2)$ Where $X_1, ... X_n \sim$ Poisson$(\lambda)$ (independent)

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, ... , X_n \sim $ Poisson$(\lambda)$ (independence is assumed) Find the UMVUE $T(X_1,...,X_n) $ of $g(\lambda) := P(X_1+X_2+X_3=2)$

So we have $g(\lambda) := P(X_1+X_2+X_3=2) = e^{-3\lambda}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!}$

$S(\underline{X}) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete and sufficient. and $S(\underline{X}) \sim $ Poisson$(n\lambda)$

So I want to find $h$ such that  $T(\underline{X}) = h(S(\underline{X}))$.

Setting up we have $\displaystyle E[h(S)] = e^{-3\lambda}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!} \implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-n\lambda(n\lambda)^k}}{k!}h(S) = e^{-3\lambda}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!}$

The next step I made was to get a sum on the RHS so I have and moved the $e^{-n\lambda} $ over:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n\lambda)^k}{k!}h(k) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{((n-3)\lambda)^k}{k!}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n\lambda)^k}{k!} \bigg( \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(n\lambda)^{-j}(-3\lambda)^{j}\frac{(3\lambda)^2}{2!} \bigg)$

However, I don't think I have computed this correctly, from what I have above I should be able match to get this $T(\underline{X})$

Looking for input if I did this correctly.

EDIT: I have $h(S)$ but I should have $h(k)$ so I will change this

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve for $h(\cdot)$ where for every $\lambda>0$,

$$E[h(S)]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty h(k)\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^k}{k!}=c\,e^{-3\lambda}\lambda^2$$

for some positive constant $c$.

That is,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{h(k)n^k}{k!}\lambda^k=c\,e^{(n-3)\lambda}\lambda^2
=c\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(n-3)^j}{j!}\lambda^{j+2}
=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{c(n-3)^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}\lambda^{k}
$$

Now compare coefficients of $\lambda^k$.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
By *definition*, the answer is given by
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k_{1} = 0}^{\infty}{\lambda^{k_{1}}\expo{-\lambda} \over k_{1}!}
\sum_{k_{2} = 0}^{\infty}{\lambda^{k_{2}}\expo{-\lambda} \over k_{2}!}
\sum_{k_{3} = 0}^{\infty}{\lambda^{k_{3}}\expo{-\lambda} \over k_{3}!}\
\overbrace{\bracks{z^{2}}z^{k_{1} + k_{2} + k_{3}}}^{\ds{\large \delta_{k_{1} + k_{2} + k_{3}, 2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\expo{-3\lambda}\bracks{z^{2}}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\lambda z}^{k} \over k!}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\expo{-3\lambda}\
\underbrace{\bracks{z^{2}}\expo{3\lambda z}}
_{\ds{{\pars{3\lambda}^{2} \over 2!}}} =
\bbx{\large{9 \over 2}\,\lambda^{2}\expo{-3\lambda}} \\ &
\end{align}